# Search 32 character long directories only with find

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

Let say I have a directory with a lot of subdirectories:

```
04762b39018e3cf4b1a2c6a304919b75
06e0caf156de30dd962cf6b9300aba66
1f1d0cb1b810336299cda5426d0f12f5
2fe7a428eb303da6846800fa20ab7ed4
41e0136413703b0685d6799f8a22a8e6
asdf
1234
Databases
```

Some of this directories are exact 32 characters long, (md5hash actually) and I would like to find them. Recursive search is not required in this case. I tried with this command:

```
find /root/my/subdir -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '^.*[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$'
```

and I would get result:

```
04762b39018e3cf4b1a2c6a304919b75
06e0caf156de30dd962cf6b9300aba66
1f1d0cb1b810336299cda5426d0f12f5
2fe7a428eb303da6846800fa20ab7ed4
41e0136413703b0685d6799f8a22a8e6
```

but I didn't get anything. In my case, I would prefer `find` for this, because then it is easy to pass bash commands later, but anything bash compatible one-liner will be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your version of `find` you might only need to turn on `egrep`:

```bash
$ find /root/my/subdir -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype egrep -regex '^.*[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$'
```

Answer (score 2):

For BSD / MacOS `find` try escaping the curly brackets in the quantifier:

```
find /root/my/subdir -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '^.*[a-fA-F0-9]\{32\}$'
```

See: [find command with regex quantifier e.g. {1,2}](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67198/255201)

Comment: You forgot the `-regextype sed` option from the answer you copied. What exactly works also depends on which version of `find` you have. BSD / MacOS `find` wants the backslashes; but the regular expression is applied to the entire path, not just the file name. So, `find /path/to/subdir -maxdepth 1 -regex '/path/to/subdir/[a-fA-F0-9\{32\}'` would work. (The `^` and `$` anchors are superfluous, as `find` requires the path to match the regex entirely.)

Comment: @tripleee thx I edited the answer I had indeed tested it for zsh on Mac

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run commands on the matching directories then shell [glob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) patterns may be a convenient way to find them.  For instance, this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code (tested with Bash and Dash) uses the `printf` command to print the paths to the directories:

```
pat='[[:xdigit:]]'
pat=$pat$pat
pat=$pat$pat$pat$pat
pat=$pat$pat$pat$pat

for dir in /root/my/subdir/$pat/; do
    printf '%s\n' "$dir"
done
```